# Spring Security - Role check fails permanently

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to learn Spring Security and want to secure an API. I want a login form with database authentication on the one hand, and on the other hand a OAuth2 authentication.
But I am stuck at the first task. The problem is that the application doesn't accept my roles and I have no idea why.

Here's my Config class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username,password,enabled FROM users WHERE username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, authority FROM authorities WHERE username=?");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/createTrack").hasRole("CREATOR")
            .antMatchers("/getTrack").hasAnyRole("CREATOR", "USER")
            .antMatchers("/test").hasRole("CREATOR")
            .antMatchers("/all").permitAll()
            .and().formLogin();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
    // TODO: Change this to hashed password (this is for demo purposes)
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}
}
```

Everything is made like descriped in the Spring documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-jdbc

I worked out a few endpoints of my API to test the logged in user's name and role. Everything works fine - the login seems to work great, also the role is correct.

But when I try to call an endpoint that's only accessible for one or both specific roles, it gets me a 403 error response.

What am I doing wrong? I tried a lot of things and it still does not work.

Thanks!

PS: I am using MyBatis (task from my company) - if that matters in any way?

Comment: Hey Toerktumlare, thank you, you brought me to the solution! CORS was not a problem but I enabled debugging and saw that Spring was looking for roles with the prefix "ROLE_" in the database. As my roles were stored as "CREATOR" and "USER" they could not be found.

I just wonder if this behavior can be configuired? So that roles can just have their name without prefix, for example...?

Comment: First of all, dont ask new questions in comments, stack overflow is not a forum, its a Q&A site and a last resort. Asking on stack overflow tokes up someones time and should not be done lightly. Second of all did you read the spring security reference documentation, and read up on your problem as to WHY the roles are prefixed, and how this is done, and how to configure it? If not i always suggest you do that. You dont ask stack overflow how to for instance enable debugg logging.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to stackoverflow hence I am not so familiar with best practices here. All clear then. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys for your help!
Toerktumlare's answer brought me to the solution. I turned on Debug Logging as you suggested. CORS was not the problem, but reading the debug messages brought me on the right way.

The problem was minor though. I stored the roles in the database as "CREATOR" or "USER". Debug messages showed me that **Spring was looking for "ROLE_CREATOR" or "ROLE_USER"** and - because my roles weren't saved this way - didn't find them. Hence I got a 403 HTTP response.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).